# Facebook Get Friends who are tagged with Graph API

Tags: graph, facebook, tags, photos

The application I am working on has the following permissions:

read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos,friends_photos,friends_photo_video_tags,user_photo_video_tags

When doing the query, only the photos **owned by the user** show up. Any picture that is on a friends album does not show up.

This happens even if all privacy settings under the "Your Privacy Settings >> Applications, Games and Websites." are enabled.

I am using the following: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was all caused by a facebook bug. For future reference check bugs.developers.facebook.com if something seems very odd!